# I'm getting a Server Error Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting this message on my localhost Error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely 
forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you 
might have mixed up default and named imports. '
```

I have cancelled out all my pages on my VS Code and just have index.js and _app.js active. When I delete the components on my index.js file I still get the same message, can anyone help on how to troubleshoot this error?

Troubleshooting my error message on localhost:

```
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import Image from "next/image";
import lightningbolt from "../public/lightningbolt.svg";
import lowcost from "../public/lowcost.svg";
import globe from "../public/globe.svg";
import peoplePic from "../public/people.svg";
import peopleMobPic from "../public/peopleMobile.svg";
import Tooltip from "../components/Tooltip";
import pipesMob from "../public/pipesMob.svg";
import pipes from "../public/pipes.svg";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-[#F5f5f5] pt-6 lg:pt-13.5">
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <header>
            <Navbar />
          </header>
          <main className="flex-1">
            <div className="relative left-1/2 mt-12 min-w[100vw] translate-x-[-50%]">
              <div className="relative mx-auto pb-30 lg:pb-30">
                <div className="px-6 md:px-8.5 lg:px-20">
                  <div className="mx-auto max-w-container">
                    <section className="h-screen w-screen">
                      <div class="my-20">
                        <h1 class="lg:w-6/12 pb-20 max-md:text-5xl max-md:mt-16 max-md:pb-10 max-md:w-auto">
                          Connecting the world through{" "}
                          <div className="flex">
                            <Image
                              class=" lg:h-14  max-md:w-auto "
                              src={lightningbolt}
                              alt=""
                            />{" "}
                            instant
                            <Image
                              className="relative lg:h-14  max-md:w-auto "
                              src={lowcost}
                              alt=""
                            />
                            low cost{" "}
                          </div>
                          <div className="flex">
                            <Image
                              className="relative lg:h-14 max-md:w-auto"
                              src={globe}
                              alt=""
                            />
                        
                          </div>
                        </h1>
                        <div className="max-md:mx-auto">
                          <Image
                            class="lg:absolute top-40  right-0 max-md:hidden max-lg:hidden  md:w-5/12 lg:w-5/12 xl:w-6+/12"
                            src={peoplePic}
                            alt=""
                          />
                          <Image
                            class="max-md:block max-md:mx-auto max-2xl:hidden 2xl:hidden xl:hidden lg:hidden md:hidden"
                            src={peopleMobPic}
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="max-md:block w-full max-md:w-screen max-md:h-screen lg:w-9/12 xl:w-4/5 ">
                          <p class="float-left py-2 mr-16 pl-0 w-1/4 leading-7 md:block max-md:w-auto">
                            {" "}
                            {" "}
                            <Tooltip description="">
                              Lightning Network,
                            </Tooltip>
                            
                          </p>
                          <p class="float-left py-2 pl-0 w-1/4 leading-7 max-md:w-auto">
                            {" "}
                            {" "}
                            <Tooltip description="">
                              
                            </Tooltip>
                          
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </section>

                    <section className="h-screen w-screen max-md:w-full max-md:h-full max-md:block">
                      <div className="2xl:hidden xl:hidden lg:hidden md:hidden max-md:relative max-md:left-0 max-md:w-full max-md:max-w-full">
                        <Image className="absolute " src={pipesMob} alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="grid grid-col-2 grid-row-2 grid-flow-col max-md:block ">
                        <div className="relative top-20 max-md:block max-md:top-0">
                          <h2>Wallet Users</h2>
                          <p className="w-9/12 max-md:block max-md:w-full">
                            
                          </p>
                          <div className="relative top-11 left-24 max-md:block max-md:top-0 max-md:left-0 ">
                            <Link href="/about">Learn more</Link>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="relative top-64 right-14 max-md:block max-md:right-0 max-md:top-0">
                          <h2>Businesses</h2>
                          <p className="w-9/12 max-md:block max-md:w-full">
                            
                          </p>
                          <a
                            href="mailto:inquiries@cequals.xyz"
                            target="_blank"
                            className="relative top-11 left-14 max-md:top-0 max-md:left-0"
                            rel="noreferrer"
                          >
                            <p>Contact Us</p>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="relative top-96 right-44 max-md:block max-md:right-0 max-md:top-0">
                          <h2>Lightning Node Operators</h2>
                          <p className="w-9/12 max-md:block max-md:w-full">
                           
                          </p>
                          <a
                            href="mailto:node@cequals.xyz"
                            target="_blank"
                            className=""
                            rel="noreferrer"
                          >
                            {" "}
                            <p>Node Questions</p>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="">
                        <Image
                          className="absolute left-0 w-full max-w-full h-auto max-md:hidden max-lg:hidden"
                          src={pipes}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </section>
                    <Footer />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

````
import "../styles/global.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

<Head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="titla, meta, nextjs" />
  <meta name="author" content="Syamlal CM" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</Head>;

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```
````

Comment: Please share a reproducible code snippet for us to help.

Comment: sharing code snippet now :)

Comment: @tobimori this is all the index.js page code and my _app.js code

Comment: Why is the head code above your function in _app.js?

Comment: @tobimori is it incorrect to put it there? I'm pretty new to next.js, is this the cause of the error im having? I've just removed it if that's the case, but still getting the same error on my localhost

Comment: Yes, it's likely the cause of your issue. You need to put it in the <Layout> component.

Comment: I've just moved in into the Layout component but still getting the same error message @tobimori

Comment: I've also been getting this message too on my localhost ' 'Check the render method of Home.' @tobimori

Comment: You need to narrow down what's causing the error. Your `Home` component renders a whole bunch of stuff, comment it all out and render the components one by one until you get error

Comment: I'm just doing this now and the first error i get it when I render the Navbar @tobimori I can't see what's wrong though as all the syntax looks fine to me

Comment: I'm adding this as an import for the navbar ```import Navbar from "../components/navbar";```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, putting the Head component in the correct position should fix the issue.

```
import "../styles/global.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>

      <Head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="titla, meta, nextjs" />
        <meta name="author" content="Syamlal CM" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```